# Redirect domain to the new one with language subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I having a problem with redirection of my website. A few days ago I bought a `.com` domain. There are two languages: Italian and German. German website was set on `example.de` and English version on `example.it`.

Now I changed it to `.com` domain: `example.com` with subfolders: `example.com/it/` and `example.com/it/`.

How to redirect all links from `example.it` to `example.com/it/` and `example.de` to `example.com/de/`.

...and following subfolders.

I was trying with

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/de/ [R=301,L]
```

But without success.

Comment: What do you mean by "without success" exactly? The rule as posted would redirect _everything_ to the homepage on `/de/` - is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my post. -> .de domain to .com/de subfolder. And .it domain to .com/it subfolder. Ofcourse with following subfolder like /news/article/my-article, /contact /about etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.de$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/de/ [R=301,L]
> ```

Having captured the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, you are missing the corresponding backreference in the *substitution* string, so this will redirect everything to the homepage, ie. `example.de/<url>` to `example.com/de/` - the `<url>` is lost.

However, you can handle both TLDs with a single rule. Since the TLD is the same as the subdirectory.

I'm assuming all three domains resolve to the same place.

Try the following instead in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.(de|it) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference refers to the captured TLD from the preceding *CondPattern*. And the `$1` backreference contains the URL-path captured in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The `RewriteBase` directive is not required here.

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the erroneous 301 (*permanent*) redirect will have been cached.

---

> **UPDATE#1:** This is Polylang plugin for Wordpress.

In which case, this redirect directive must go at the very top of your `.htaccess` file, before any existing WordPress directives, including before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

---

> **UPDATE#2:** I also have `.cz` domain and subfolder is `/cs` (ISO standard)

Since the TLD and subdirectory are different, you will need to add another rule to handle this. (This can go before or after the above rule, since there is no conflict.)

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.cz [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/cs/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does not redirect me correctly. When I visit page from direct link like: mywebsite.de/mypage/sub-page it still on .de domain not on .com/de

Comment: @Mike If you are still seeing `example.de` then this directive is not doing anything at all. Where are you placing this rule? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? I'm assuming all 3 domains resolve to the same place?

Comment: This is Polylang plugin for Wordpress. I am using .htaccess to do that. So far I have changed Polyang settings from domain to subfolder settings, and also WP siteurl is on .com domain now. Everything works good when I click links on website, but no direct links. When I paste URL to my web browser with old link with .de domain it still opens .de URL not .com/de/

Comment: Yes, but _where_ are you putting these directives exactly? And where do all 3 of these domains resolve? (As requested in my comment above.) If you are using WordPress, then these directives must go at the very top of your `.htaccess` file, _before_ all the existing WordPress directives. Before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

Comment: Ohhhh I see. Yes you are genius! 1 line of htaccess works good for me! Thank you. But I have another problem. I also have .cz domain and subfolder is /cs (ISO standard) and domain is .cz. How to redirect it?

Comment: @Mike You're welcome. You will need to add another rule to handle the `.cz` / `/cs` request - I've updated my answer.